# System repair disc for windows 8

Tags: windows-8, system-repair-disc

Recently, I got a new Surface Pro, and I am creating a system image and a system repair disk to prevent an unexpected crash.

I have a system repair disc created from windows 7. Can I use it for windows 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only use the repair disk which matches to the current Windows version. If you use a Win7 DVD to restore Win8 or Win8 DVD to restore Win7 you get an error message.

I tried this out last year.